# how to filter following map?

Tags: java, dictionary

I have got these values in my `HashMap` ,

```
"ver":"a"
"ver":"b"
"ver":"c"
"os":"d"
"os":"e"
```

i need only:

```
"os":"d"
"os":"e"
```

My code is:

```
String[] eachPair = myString.split(",");
Map<String,String> pairs = new HashMap<String,String>();

for(String pair: eachPair) {
    pairs.put(pair.substring(0, pair.indexOf(":")).trim(), pair.substring(pair.indexOf(":")+1));
}
pairs.get("os");
```

but its not working. please help

Answer (score 1):

An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

Answer (score 1):

`HahMap` doesn't allows duplicate keys.So I recommand to use `Guava's MultiMap` or `apache's MultiValueMap`
Please look into
the sample code reference of MultiMap: http://tomjefferys.blogspot.in/2011/09/multimaps-google-guava.html
the sample code reference of MultiValueMap: http://java.dzone.com/articles/allowing-duplicate-keys-java

Comment: @JitendraKhedar Please look into my updated answer for sample links

Comment: @Prabhakar , I have successfully used Multimap, it stores same value twice, again filetaration needed??

Comment: @JitendraKhedar do you want to store unique values and duplicate key..?

Comment: syntax for "pairs.put" would be what ?

Comment: @Prabhaker: That makes no sense.  It sounds like you mean a `SetMultimap<String, String>`.

Answer (score 1):

`Map` should have unique keys only, If you add a value with the same key which is already exist in the map, value for that key will be override and you will lost the old value.